# google endpoints restrict access to mobile clients only

Tags: python, api, mobile, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been reading a lot about this google endpoints and I have trying to something that is not quite easy to guess. After you create a google cloud endpoint server and you deploy it is open to any HTTP request (unauthenticated). In the cloud endpoint documentation (referring to using authentication) you can read about setting OAuth2.0 to authenticate users with google account but there is no documentation about restrict the endpoint service to a specific mobile app (android or ios) and discard all other HTTP requests. So the question is how to authenticate mobile apps (no users) and prevent HTTP request (unauthenticated)? I'am building my server API(enpoints) based on Python.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to restrict your Endpoint to a specific application you can use OAuth2. This is because the OAuth2 flow does user authentication and in-turn the OAuth2 flow inherently authenticates the application requesting the OAuth2 access.

These two client samples detail how to enable authenticated calls on the client side. You have to register your apps in the Developer Console at http://cloud.google.com/console/ .

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android (Starting after the Note in the readme)
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-ios/ (Step 8 in README)

authedGreeting is the authenticated call and you would check the User object in the method's backend project for null. If empty then you can immediately throw an unauthorized exception.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven 
Specifically, optional Step 2 in the README tells Cloud Endpoints to start looking for OAuth2 tokens in the request. If the Endpoints exposed method has a User parameter. It will populate it with a user instance only if an OAuth2 token was found, was generally valid, and the token was issued to a client ID defined in the API annotation on the service class.

Answer (score 0):

During the setup of your endpoints API, in `clientIds` list you provide your `WEB_CLIENT_ID`, `ANDROID_CLIENT_ID`, and `IOS_CLIENT_ID` for example. These values tell the Google App Engine that your application will respond to HTTPS requests from web browsers and Android/iOS installed applications.

When your clients first connect your server, they must obtain an OAuth 2.0 token in order to the communication be secure and that is the reason why you use the `WEB_CLIENT_ID` in your installed client application. This `WEB_CLIENT_ID` is unique to your Google Cloud app and through it your client becomes capable of obtain an `access_token` and a `renew_token` to communicate with your *backend server* and *your server only*. This is a [cross-client authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth).

So, if you need only the `WEB_CLIENT_ID` to obtain the `access_token` and the `renew_token`, why you need the `ANDROID_CLIENT_ID` and `IOS_CLIENT_ID`? For security reasons.

The `ANDROID_CLIENT_ID` is linked to a RSA signature key through the SHA1 informed at backend setup. Thus your GAE app will grant `(access_token, renew_token)` only installed apps signed with the same key listed at your application console (and of course in your `clientIds` list)

Finally Android apps signed with different or not signed will not receive any `access_token`, being unable to establish the secure communication channel or even communicate with your server.